# Pass Range instance through different contexts on Opera Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, opera

I am developing an extension for Opera, which is an absolute first for me, and at some point I want to save the context where a user highlighted some text, so that when the user refreshes the site, or reopens it later, the highlighted text will be highlighted. I execute a js script that does the highlighting, and it sends it back to the background process, which stores it in an array (for now I want it to be persistent at least through a single session of Opera). Then, once any tabs finishes loading, the background process has it run a different js script that highlights any previously saved text from that webpage. To do this, I have a highlight object, that currently has the highlighted text, along with the source url, and an ID. I tried passing the range that I used for highlighting the text, but as soon as the range object gets sent to the background process, it is just received as a generic object, which I cannot use.

So the problem I am facing right now is that once a page loads, I know what pieces of text had previously been highlighted on that page, but I don't have a way to highlight them.

I guess what I was trying to do (passing the range, or the start and end containers) didn't really make a lot of sense, but I can't think of another way to do it, nor can I find anything online to help.

Comment: The page might change during refresh, so a simple range will probably not work

Comment: DOM elements/objects, `Range` included, are not JSON-ifiable thus cannot be messaged nor saved in chrome.storage so you'll have to use some other method of identifying the selection.

Comment: Idea: you can store offsets of the Range elements in a flat list of all elements e.g. `document.getElementsByTagName('*').indexOf(element)`